# How to calculate off a filtered table in Excel, possibly use VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, datatable, calculated-columns

Brand new VBA user here:

I'm trying to have a calculated table form from a filtered table in excel. I know the filtered table only hides values so doing any offset or indexing still returns the hidden filtered values, so the internet has pushed me towards using VBA.

In using VBA I can't seem to plug a variable into a range.value that grows over each loop so the cells grow until the visible filtered table is finished. I believe the Do Until function is what I'm supposed to use to achieve this, but I need some major help on my code, or I'm unaware of an easier process:

Current Broken Code:

```
Sub TableCreate()

iRow = 1

iPlug = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1))

Set Rng = Range("A"iPlug)

' Store the current cell value in the dCellValues array

Range(Rng).Value = Cells(iRow, 1).Value

iRow = iRow + 1

iPlug = iPlug + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Thank You,

EEE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a numeric variable in a cell address, you have to concatenate the number with an ampersand `&` sign.

```
Set Rng = Range("A" & iPlug)
```

It also looks like you only need one variable, because iPlug and iRow will always be the same value.

If you declare the `Rng` variable as a range, then you can use the variable directly.

```
    Dim Rng as Range
'... code leading up to this ...
    Set Rng = Range("A"&iPlug)

    ' Store the current cell value in the dCellValues array

    Rng = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
```

You could also use the Range method directly, without using a variable.

```
Range("A"&iPlug) = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you...
Was wondering if there is a way to calculate off a filtered table with out using VBA in Excel anyway. I want the data to change on one sheet as I manually filter a table on another, but simply filtering (hiding) rows doesn't allow for the other table to calculate differently. 

Reason I ask is once I finish this I have to present my method to a coworker who doesn't know VBA at all, so a solution with out using VBA would be ideal :), but if impossible then I'll have to make do.

Comment: It depends on what you want to calculate. Subtotal() has parameters that will sum only visible data. Also, consider using a pivot table, or using Sumifs(), Countifs() etc functions to define the conditions for the calculations.